# Modify x-axis labels in each facet

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this chart - I would like to add to each label the text `N=xx` to denote the number of observations. I know how to do this and I have done that on charts with no facets.

When I tried that on the faceted chart it did not work, (I got the same N on the open tick on all 3 charts, the same N on the Restricted, etc.)

I hope someone can point the way to a solution, how do I control the elements on a given facet?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

stat_sum_single <- function(fun, geom="point", ...) {
  stat_summary(fun.y=fun, fill="red", geom=geom, size = 5, shape=24)
}

set.seed(1)
data1 <- data.frame(Physicians_In=sample(1:3,100,replace=T),Physicians_Out=sample(1:3,100,replace=T),share=runif(100,0,1))
data1$Physicians_In <- factor(data1$Physicians_In,levels=c(1,2,3),labels=c("Open","Restricted","Closed"))
data1$Physicians_Out <- factor(data1$Physicians_Out,levels=c(1,2,3),labels=c("Open","Restricted","Closed"))

access_ch3 <- ggplot(data1,aes(x=Physicians_In,y=share,fill=Physicians_In))+geom_boxplot()+stat_sum_single(mean)
access_ch3 <- access_ch3 +geom_jitter(position = position_jitter(width = .2),color="blue")+theme_bw()
access_ch3 <- access_ch3 + theme(legend.position="none") +scale_y_continuous("Gammagard Share",labels=percent)
gpo_labs5 <- paste(gsub("/","-\n",names(table(data1$Physicians_Out)),fixed=T),"\n(N=",table(data1$Physicians_Out),")",sep="")
access_ch3 <- access_ch3 + scale_x_discrete("Physician Access (In Hospital)",labels=gpo_labs5)
access_ch3 <- access_ch3 +facet_grid(.~Physicians_Out,labeller=label_both)
access_ch3
```

I tried creating the 9 labels and passing that vector to the `scale_x_discrete` element, that just recycled the first 3, so it also did not solve the issue.

Comment: Is is not clear. Do you want to modify axis ticks or facets labels?

Comment: the axis tick labels - if on the first facet for Open there are 6 observations I want it to show "Open (N=6)", if on the second Open had 9 that one would be "open (N=9)"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is not exactly what you want to do , but I think this can be helpful ( at least a good start)

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plyr)
data1 <- ddply(data1,.(Physicians_Out,Physicians_In),transform,label = length(share))
ggplot(data1,aes(x=Physicians_In,y=share,fill=Physicians_In))+ 
    geom_boxplot() + 
    stat_sum_single(mean) +
    facet_grid(.~Physicians_Out,labeller=label_both,scales='free_x') +
    stat_summary(fun.y=min,aes(label=paste0('N=',label)),geom='text',col='blue',cex=5)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for the answer, I want to add the number of observations for each of the boxplots I am showing

Comment: @user1617979 I completely change my answer.

Comment: thanks, this actually works great and I like it as it allows the use of facet_grid. I was able to align them at the bottom by adding y=0 inside the aes() statement in stat_summary. I also learned how to use transform in ddply which I was not familiar with (will save me many merges)

Answer (score 17):

With the same data I followed a four step approach.

First: subsetting the data

```
open <- subset(data1, Physicians_Out == "Open")
restr <- subset(data1, Physicians_Out == "Restricted")
closed <- subset(data1, Physicians_Out == "Closed")
```

Second: creating the labels for the different subsets

```
labs.open <- paste(gsub("/","-\n",names(table(open$Physicians_In)),fixed=T),
               "\n(N=",table(open$Physicians_In),")",sep="")
labs.restr <- paste(gsub("/","-\n",names(table(restr$Physicians_In)),fixed=T),
               "\n(N=",table(restr$Physicians_In),")",sep="")
labs.closed <- paste(gsub("/","-\n",names(table(closed$Physicians_In)),fixed=T),
               "\n(N=",table(closed$Physicians_In),")",sep="")
```

Third: creating a theme for removing the y-axis labels & text for the 2nd & 3rd sub-graphs

```
mytheme <- theme(
  axis.title.y = element_blank(),
  axis.text.y = element_blank(),
  axis.ticks.y = element_blank()
)
```

Finally: creating the graph

```
p1 <- ggplot(open,aes(x=Physicians_In,y=share,fill=Physicians_In)) +
  geom_boxplot() + stat_sum_single(mean) + 
  geom_jitter(position = position_jitter(width = .2),color="blue") +
  guides(fill=FALSE) +
  ggtitle(paste("Physician Access (Out): Open\nN = (", nrow(open), ")\n")) +
  scale_y_continuous("Gammagard Share",labels=percent) +
  scale_x_discrete("\nPhysician Access (In Hospital)",labels=labs.open) +
  theme_bw()

p2 <- ggplot(restr,aes(x=Physicians_In,y=share,fill=Physicians_In)) +
  geom_boxplot() + stat_sum_single(mean) + 
  geom_jitter(position = position_jitter(width = .2),color="blue") +
  guides(fill=FALSE) +
  ggtitle(paste("Physician Access (Out): Restricted\nN = (", nrow(restr), ")\n")) +
  scale_x_discrete("\nPhysician Access (In Hospital)",labels=labs.restr) +
  theme_bw() + mytheme

p3 <- ggplot(closed,aes(x=Physicians_In,y=share,fill=Physicians_In)) +
  geom_boxplot() + stat_sum_single(mean) + 
  geom_jitter(position = position_jitter(width = .2),color="blue") +
  guides(fill=FALSE) +
  ggtitle(paste("Physician Access (Out): Closed\nN = (", nrow(closed), ")\n")) +
  scale_x_discrete("\nPhysician Access (In Hospital)",labels=labs.closed) +
  theme_bw() + mytheme

library(gridExtra)

grid.arrange(p1, p2, p3, ncol=3)
```

Which gives the following result:

[image]

Comment: That's a nice workaround but you loose the facets headers

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way I know how to do this is to make a new variable for the x-axis, with the label you want, and then to use `scales="free"` to only show the levels that exist for each facet.

```
set.seed(1)
levs <- factor(1:3, levels=1:3, labels=c("Open","Restricted","Closed"))
data1 <- data.frame(Physicians_In  = sample(levs, 100, replace=TRUE),
                    Physicians_Out = sample(levs, 100, replace=TRUE),
                    share = runif(100, 0, 1)) |>
  mutate(n=n(), .by=c(Physicians_In, Physicians_Out),
         Physicians_In_N = sprintf("%s\n(N=%d)", Physicians_In, n))

ggplot(data1, aes(x=Physicians_In_N, y=share, fill=Physicians_In)) + 
  facet_grid(.~Physicians_Out, labeller=label_both, scales="free") +
  geom_boxplot() +
  stat_sum_single(mean) + 
  geom_jitter(position = position_jitter(width = .2), color="blue") + 
  theme_bw() + theme(legend.position="none") + 
  scale_y_continuous(name="Gammagard Share", labels=percent) +
  scale_x_discrete(name="Physician Access (In Hospital)")
```

[image: My version of the desired plot.]