# make one panel blank in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) 
p + geom_point()+facet_grid(cyl ~ vs)+theme_bw()
```

[image: Pic]

I would like to make the panel (1 vs 8 in the lower right hand corner) blank where no data points are shown, but at the same time, I would like to keep this arrangement.

so `facet_wrap(cyl ~ vs)` could not solve my problem.

maybe more general question is that is it possible to arrange each panel in ggplot2?

Comment: I gave up trying to do it in ggplot a while ago, it's straightforward with the regular plot command. Also, you might try sending this to the ggplot mailing list.

Comment: But the arrangement **is** preserved if you use `facet_wrap(cyl ~ vs, ncol=2)`, although the labeling changes slightly. Is this not your intention?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You change the table grobs.

```
## get the table grobs
g1 <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(p))

library(gtable)
library(grid)
## here the main modification
## change one panel by a new rectangle.
pp <- gtable_add_grob(g1,rectGrob(gp=gpar(col=NA)),t=8,l=6,b=8,r=6)
grid.draw(pp)
```

[image]

Comment: `g = ggplotGrob(p); ;g$grobs[[max(which(g$layout$name == "panel"))]] = nullGrob(); grid.draw(g)`

Comment: @agstudy, Thank you very much agstudy, this is exactly what i want.

Answer (score 18):

You can do that, but not with `facet_wrap` (as far as I know). Create your seperate sub-plots. For a detailed step by step approach, [see my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20524630/modify-x-axis-labels-in-each-facet/20528655#20528655).

Create a blank plot & with the package `gridExtra` you can combine the plots:

```
library(gridExtra)
library(grid)

blank <- grid.rect(gp=gpar(col="white"))

grid.arrange(plot1, plot2, blank, plot3, ncol=2)
```

This approach will give you also a lot influence on the appearance of you final plot (IMHO).

Comment: @joaoal no it isn't; `grid.arrange` is a function from the `gridExtra`-package

Comment: @Jaap but `grid.rect` requires `library("grid")`

Comment: This did not work for me, there was a huge blank space created before the plots...