# To make a ggplot2 facet_grid panel only where there is information

Tags: r, ggplot2, grid, facet

I have points made in different months and different years. And here's what I get:

```
ggplot() +
  geom_point(
    data = reka.coord,
    colour = "black",
    shape = 20,
    size = 5,
    aes(X, Y, group = biotop)
  ) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "none"
  ) +
  facet_grid(year ~ month) +
  theme(strip.text = element_text(size = 20, colour = "black"))
```

[image]

Here's what I want:

[image]

`fascet_wrap` I tried too:

[image]

Comment: So your desired result is the "so I can do" plot? Then you want `facet_wrap`, not `facet_grid`. Try `facet_wrap(~year + month)`

Comment: @MrFlick This version of my 3 figures (

Comment: check out this answer, that should help you solve your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20553168/3052148