# How to leave a gap without a graphic in a specific position with "grid.arrange" in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have 8 plots (`P1`,`P2`,`P3`,`P4`,`P5`,`P6`,`P7`,`P8`) and for illustration purposes, I want to display them all together (that is, in a 3x3 graph). However, also for illustration purposes, I want to display `P1` and `P2` in the upper row, `P3`,`P4` and `P5` in the middle row, and `P6`,`P7` and`P8` in the lower row.

How can I arrange the plots in order to get that? I would like to leave the gap in the upper right corner for instance. So far, I've done this:

```
grid.arrange(P1,P2,P3,P4,P5,P6,P7,P8, ncol=3)
```

Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: I believe you can add a blank grob to your `grid.arrange` function. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20552226/make-one-panel-blank-in-ggplot2) answer by @Jaap

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `layout_matrix` option of `grid.arrange`. You just need to build a matrix where the value of each cell indicates which plot should be drawn in that portion of the matrix. Here's one example

```
# sample plots
library(ggplot2)
P <- lapply(1:8, function(i) ggplot(data.frame(x=1, y=1), aes(x,y)) + geom_text(label=i))

# create layout
m <- matrix(c(rep(1:2, each=3), rep(3:8, each=2)), ncol=6, byrow=TRUE)
grid.arrange(grobs=P, layout_matrix = m)
```

[image]

Since the matrix has to have a consistent number of rows and columns, we create one with 6 columns. We assign the top left three cells to plot 1, the top right three cells to plot 2, then on the rest of the rows, we assign two cells per plot.

```
# m
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    1    1    1    2    2    2
[2,]    3    3    4    4    5    5
[3,]    6    6    7    7    8    8
```

If you just wanted a blank cell in one of the positions, you can use an NA in the layout matrix (and go back to using a 3x3 matrix since we don't need to match up two and three column rows)

```
m <- matrix(c(1,2,NA,3:8), ncol=3, byrow=TRUE)
grid.arrange(grobs=P, layout_matrix = m)
```

[image]