# Small multiples scatter plot with identical x and y axis in R?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, scatter-plot

I am making a visualization that involves factors, ratios, and countries. There are about 15 factors and I am trying to use  small multiples to create a large graph where the X and Y axes are the factors, ie, roughly:

Population

Num of Cars

Num of houses

```
               Num of Houses     Num of Cars     Population
```

Where each intersection would be a plot of the values for each country (so, the plot at the intersection of # of Cars and # of Houses would be # of houses vs # of cars, etc). I currently have a data frame with the information with column headers: country, factors, ratios. I've tried using a few methods (`facet_grid`, `facet_wrap`, etc), but just can't get an output - when I run the script, a blank screen pops up. I haven't been able to figure out how to successfully google the type of small multiples plot i'm trying to create and am having a bit of trouble. I'm also brand new to R and have been stuck for a great many hours.

Any advice?

Edited: More information

some sample data:

```
                        factor     country year     ratio  
1                           LiteracyRate Afghanistan 2000 0.3622047    
2       PostSecondarySchoolAgePopulation Afghanistan 2011 0.9272919    
3 PrePrimaryEducationSchoolAgePopulation Afghanistan 2012 0.9397506    
4    PrimaryEducationSchoolAgePopulation Afghanistan 2009 0.9344603
5           SecondarySchoolAgePopulation Afghanistan 2008 0.9301103
```

(I have this data for every country, and more factors than shown, also)

code that has been most successful so far:

```
try <-  read.table(".../temper.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",")

remr <- ggplot(try, aes(factor, ratio)) + geom_point()

remr + facet_grid(factor ~ factor)
```

Graph produced: http://www.flickr.com/photos/94273266@N05/11411186776/

Comment: People are generally much more happy to help if you provide a [**minimal, reproducible example**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610) together with the code you have tried. Thanks!

Comment: sorry @Henrik, just added more info

Comment: Thanks for the example data. Sorry, but I am not entirely sure what you are looking for. To make a "grid" of plots defined by factors, you need two _different_ factors, one for the horizontal and one for the vertical direction. Have a look at [**this tutorial**](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/), especially the chapter about [**facets**](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Facets_%28ggplot2%29/). Or perhaps you are looking for a scatter plot matrix? Then check e.g. `ggpairs` in `GGally` package.

Comment: Ah a scatter plot matrix is the correct terminology. I wanted to have the same set of factors on both axes so that I could see correlations between ratios for two factors at a time. I was able to get a more accurate version of what i was looking for still using facets: http://www.flickr.com/photos/94273266@N05/11411801083/ ... but I can't generate the information for any factor column except Literacy Rate currently

Comment: Thanks for the tip for ggpairs -- i found this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/7OXSp.png which is the structure i'm looking for, so I'll investigate that more

Comment: Also check `pairs` in `base` R.

Comment: You might also look at the `gridExtra` package. [See my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20524630/modify-x-axis-labels-in-each-facet/20528655#20528655) for a step by step approach for combining several plots and still having complete control over the appearance of the sub-plots.

Comment: the flickr is not working