# How to specify different labels for each distinct panels when using facet_grid in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is it possible to specify distinct labels axes in each panel within ggplot?

For example:

`ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = carat, y = price)) + geom_point() + facet_grid(~cut)`

In this figure we have five panels, I would like to specify my own label for each of them. The default output is to produce one label for all the axes.

Is there a solution that doesn't involve using grid.arrange as is done here:

[Modify x-axis labels in each facet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20524630/modify-x-axis-labels-in-each-facet)

Comment: Possibly editing the grobs directly...

Comment: With a categorical variable on the x axis as in the linked question, you could make the labels a new variable, map it the x axis, and use `scales = "free"`.

Answer (score 1):

(I'm assuming you're referring to axis *titles*, not *labels*.)

Out of principle, no. The philosophy behind facets is that they share common aesthetic mappings. But we can trick `ggplot` to get what we want, for example:

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = carat, y = price)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  facet_grid(~cut, switch = 'x') +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        strip.background = element_blank())
```

The trick is to `switch` the facet strips to the bottom of the plot. Then we turn off the strip background and the original x-axis title to create the appearance of separate axis titles.

[image]

(You may also want to change `strip.text.x = element_text(size = ??)` to the same size as the y-axis title. However, it seems to not be documented what the defualt size is for axis titles.)

Comment: Nice solution. I am actually looking to change the labels though. The facets share an aesthetic mapping, but the _interpretation_ of the mapping changes across panels and I want to indicate this with the change in label.

Comment: The labels in the example are 1 to 5. It's not clear what you'd want with that.