# Modifying Y axis to present number of observations in each group

Tags: r, ggplot2, count, axis-labels, interaction

I want my plot to display how many people/observations are within each group. How can I do this? I found this answer, however I had a hard time following it.
[Modify x-axis labels in each facet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20524630/modify-x-axis-labels-in-each-facet)

```
 Rc <- iris %>%
  dplyr::group_by(Species) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(mean = mean(Petal.Length),
         se = sd(Petal.Length)/sqrt(length(Petal.Length))) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Petal.Length, y=Species)) +
  stat_slab(aes(fill = Species, )) +
   stat_dots(aes(color = Species), side = "bottom", shape = 16) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set1", aesthetics = c("fill", "color"))  +
  geom_errorbar(aes(xmin = mean - 1.96 * se,
                    xmax = mean + 1.96 * se), width = 0.2) +
  stat_summary(fun=mean, geom="point", shape=16, size=3.0) +
  theme_bw(base_size = 10) +
  theme(legend.position = "top")+
  labs(title="Raincloud plot with ggdist")
  print(Rc + labs(x = "Petal Length"))  [![Result[1]][1]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to add a new column to your dataset where you glue the number obs. per species to the species name. This column could then be mapped on `y`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggdist)

iris %>%
  dplyr::group_by(Species) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(
    mean = mean(Petal.Length),
    se = sd(Petal.Length) / sqrt(length(Petal.Length)),
    species_y = paste0(Species, "\n(", n(), ")")
  ) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Petal.Length, y = species_y)) +
  stat_slab(aes(fill = Species)) +
  stat_dots(aes(color = Species), side = "bottom", shape = 16) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set1", aesthetics = c("fill", "color")) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(
    xmin = mean - 1.96 * se,
    xmax = mean + 1.96 * se
  ), width = 0.2) +
  stat_summary(fun = mean, geom = "point", shape = 16, size = 3.0) +
  theme_bw(base_size = 10) +
  theme(legend.position = "top") +
  labs(title = "Raincloud plot with ggdist", x = "Petal Length")
```

[image]